# Odoo Server Error : from new_cause odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing near

Tags: python, parsing, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-12

i got error when i add field into views.xml file.
when i am trying to update myb custom module which a field is links to a new model i am getting.
error : odoo.tools.convert.ParseError
can you please help me
please give me answer for this.
i installed odoo 14 version on my ubuntu system
Error:
**Odoo Server Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 677, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 492, in _tag_record
    model = env[rec_model]
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/api.py", line 476, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse(self, (), ())
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'view_order_form_inherit_new'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/http.py", line 347, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/http.py", line 912, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1394, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1382, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/api.py", line 399, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/api.py", line 386, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-78>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 654, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 593, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 455, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 347, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 69, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 733, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 719, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 677, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 681, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, near\n%s' % (
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo-14/odoo-14-server/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /odoo-14/custom/addons/om_odoo_inheritance/views/sale_order.xml:4, near
<record id="ir.ui.view" model="view_order_form_inherit_new">
        <field name="name">sale.order.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='payment_term_id']" position="after">
                <field name="confirmed_user_id"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up `id` and `model`. You have to swap them:

```xml
<record id="view_order_form_inherit_new" model="ir.ui.view">
```